# IIS Url Rewrite slows down website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am using IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 for some rules in my web.config, since UrlRewriting.config is out-dated, and it is suggested to use IIS URL Rewrite instead. However, immediately after adding two simple rules to my web.config, my website is performing slowly...I am running Sql Server Express, so it's not a database issue.

The slow performance occurred immediately after reloading a web page (any page, not just the specific url sitemap.xml seen below) upon saving the rules in the web.config under `<system.webServer>`.

Any help / suggestions?

```
   <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <!-- Serve site map with proper XML content type response header. -->
    <rule name="Sitemap XML" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="sitemap.xml" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="sitemap.aspx" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
    <!-- Access block rule - is used to block all requests made to a Web site if those requests do not have the host header set. This type of rule is useful when you want to prevent hacking attempts that are made by issuing HTTP requests against the IP address of the server instead of using the host name -->
    <rule name="Fail bad requests">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <!-- HTTP to HTTPS Rule 
    <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS8 RewriteModule / URLRewrite Extremely Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972191/iis8-rewritemodule-urlrewrite-extremely-slow)